# START-OF-SELECTION not triggered in ABAP?

Tags: abap

I am studying [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430248033) book and quoting from Chapter 5:

> You are being introduced to the event START-OF-SELECTION. The first
>   thing to understand about an event is to know when an event is
>   triggered: that is, when program control jumps to the code under an
>   event.
>
> Scenario-I If there are no PARAMETERS statements in a program,
>   pressing the function key F8 will begin the execution of the program
>   starting from the first nondeclarative statement in the program.
>
> In the scenario-I (no PARAMETERS statement/s) when the program is
>   executed, control jumps to the event START-OF-SELECTION.

So here I have my sample code:

```
REPORT ZTMP_TEST_INNBOUND.

WRITE 'Hello World!'.

START-OF-SELECTION.
WRITE 'Big-Bang first..'.
```

And I am expecting that "Bing-Bang First" is printed first, but it is not the case.

Here is the output:

```
Hello World!
Big-Bang first..
```

Why is the output not the other way around? Is my understanding of what is explained in the book is wrong regarding START-OF-SELECTION ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per SAP, in an executable program, any non-declarative statements that occur between the REPORT or PROGRAM statement and the first processing block are also processed in the START-OF-SELECTION block. So in your code example, the first write will execute and then the second one.

[Here is a good reference](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/EN/54/57fe06786a11d194c90000e8353423/content.htm?frameset=/EN/9f/db9a0735c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm&current_toc=/EN/d3/2e974d35c511d1829f0000e829fbfe/plain.htm&node_id=3&show_children=false)

Comment: [Here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/EN/fc/eb2d67358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm?frameset=/EN/fc/eb2d74358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm)'s the section of the reference particularly pertaining to event blocks.

Comment: There will be an implicit START-OF-SELECTION block.